# What is the container docker is trying to start?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After running this command:

```
docker-compose -f ~/Documents/workspace/docker/project/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

I get this output:

```
project_db_1 is up-to-date
Starting project_project_1
ERROR: Cannot start container 1d7ff723db85767429d25c6236cb1c17fc332b3424f32811a071b68d84df430f: [9] System error: not a directory
```

What is that container that it is trying to start? And what is not a directory?

Comment: it's the `project` container defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file. there might be an error in that section of the file.

Comment: @warmoverflow In that section of the file there is a volumes list? Could it be referring to that? Do you know what a colon signifies? For example I may have a `path/to/file.jar:/var/app/project/file2.jar`.

Comment: That are the volume mapping between host and container. The part before `:` is host path, while after is container path, and the mapping mounts the host directory/file to the container. It is likely that Docker cannot find the file/directory on the host.

Comment: @warmoverflow Thanks. If I put the hosts paths into the terminal they are both confirmed to be directories. Would there be a reason that docker couldn't find them? Could the error also apply to an image or networks?

Comment: There could be many possible reasons. One common issue is that if you are running Docker on Windows or OS X, files must be inside your user home folder, otherwise they are not accessible to Docker.

Comment: @warmoverflow It looks like everything is in my home folder. Is it possible to see exactly what path it is failing on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110317/discussion-between-john-doe-and-warmoverflow).